# Add a new email connector to iOS

Tags: ios, email

Is there a way to add a custom email connector to iOS? So the user can config this new email type like other known email in iPhone and iPad, but the underlying is pointing to my own custom data provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, there is no way top do this. Apple does not provide any API for doing this.

You can only send e-mail using the `MFMailComposeViewController`, there is not other interaction with mail possible via the official SDK.